# vue 3 ref pushing array value infinite times

Tags: vuejs3, ref

```
    let arrayOfFunctions =  ref([])
    
    
     function getTank(tank){
    
        let url = '/gettank/'+tank;
  
        axios.get(url)
               .then(function(response){          
                arrayOfFunctions.value.push(response.data);        
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                       console.log(error);
                 });
      
        }
    
  <tr class="border-b border-slate-200" v-for="(item, index) in farray" :key="item.id">
<td>
{{getTank(item.tankno)}}
      {{arrayOfFunctions}}
</td></tr>
```

When I call its pushing same values infinite times

[image]

Comment: is `arrayOfFunctions` supposed to be the same thing as `farray`?

Comment: @cSharp no its another array for pushing axios returned values

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the infinite loop occurs because you mutate your data in `template`. When you do `getTank()` inside `td`, it mutates `arrayOfFunctions`, causing the template to re-render, which calls `getTank()` again and so on. You should try to get all the `getTank` information beforehand in `script` and just use a `v-for` on the returned array, if you can.

Comment: it won't work as all ref variables get repeated infinite times

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam could you provide more context as to why it won't work, and what ref variables are getting repeatedly infinite items?